# C# The type D must be convertible to A<C,I<T1>> in order to use it as parameter T2 in the generic type or method B<T1,T2>

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I have the following hierarchy of classes.

```
interface I<T> { }

abstract class A<T1, T2> { }

class B<T1, T2>
    where T2 : A<T1, I<T1>>
{ }

class C { }

class D : A<C, I<C>> { }

class E : B<C, D> { }
```

Compiler says "`The type D must be convertible to A<C, I<T1>> in order to use it as parameter T2 in the generic type or method B<T1,T2>`". Why does he want D to be convertible to `A<C, I<T1>>` when it intended to be convertible to `A<C, I<C>>`? I thought that compiler supposed to replace that T1 with C in this case.

Edit: Compilation fails on Unity's Mono compiler (Mono 4.4), .NET 3.5.

Comment: These types compile fine within isolation in the VS 2015/Roslyn compiler. Is this an issue with a previous compiler? If so, which one?

Comment: .net 4.5.2 build success

Comment: Please post which compiler version you're using so that others can help more easily.

Comment: It fails with Unity's Mono compiler which targets .NET 3.5.